# Installer like InnoSetup for Mac

Tags: macos, installation

I'm looking for a simple and efficient Mac installer software. For Windows, there are many good installers - Inno Setup, NSIS, etc. Anything like that available for apples?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need an installer? It's most macish to have a DMG image with the app in it, so the user can just drag it to the Programs folder.

If it's more complex, I think you have use a .pkg package. The Installer app will install the files out of it. Those packages can be created by using PackageMaker, which is brought by XCode.

Comment: Would be great if Apple had come up with a way that the .pkg could download extra files from a remote URL and show that result in the progress bar. Sure, you can hook it via preinstall script, but it doesn't update the progress bar while that runs if it takes a long time.